# Convert Nginx Conf to use different roots for each location

Tags: nginx

I am trying to modify my Nginx config so that the /tablet & /mobile locations are served from their own root.

I believe i need to add Alias definitions to my locations but not quite sure about the specifics.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/htdocs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location /mobile {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/mobile/(.*)$ /mobile/index.php?$args last;
        }
    }

    location /tablet {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/tablet/(.*)$ /tablet/index.php?$args last;
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com docker.domain.com ;

    root /var/www/htdocs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location /mobile {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/mobile/(.*)$ /mobile/index.php?$args last;
        }
    }

    location /tablet {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/tablet/(.*)$ /tablet/index.php?$args last;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

So I have tried adding the following:

```
 location /test {
      alias /var/www/htdocs/test;
    }
```

This correctly serves the files from the specified location, but if I echo server root it shows /var/www/htdocs/.

Comment: With alias nginx basically "drops" the location value (in this case test)  when looking for the path to serve files from. So your correct root, is /var/www/htdocs/ for the /test location. You can't set root to be /var/www/htdocs/test in the /test location and then serve files from /var/www/htdocs/test. You would have to move the files to /var/www/htdocs/test/test/ to do that

Comment: Not related to your actual question, but for best practices, instead of using `if (!-e $request_filename)`, use `try_files $uri /mobile/index.php?$args;` in your `/tablet` / `/mobile` location blocks.